# Group by column A, group combination of values in column B and get sum of B

Tags: mysql, grails

I have data that looks something like this

```
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  a  |
|  1  |  a  |
|  1  |  b  |
|  1  |  b  |
|  1  |  c  |
|  2  |  a  |
|  2  |  a  |
|  2  |  b  |
|  3  |  b  |
|  3  |  a  |
+-----+-----+
```

I need a query that will give me something like this.

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  | sum |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | a+b |  4  |
|  1  | c+d |  1  |
|  2  | a+b |  3  |
|  2  | c+d |  0  |
|  3  | a+b |  2  |
|  3  | c+d |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

More specifically in grails in a withCriteria. I can maybe make it work, or adjust if it's straight mysql. I need where I'm grouping by A, but want the secondary group B to be a combination of 2 different values and then a sum of the count of that combo in B.

I've seen some examples similar using CASE but haven't seen one where they combine the values in a column to get a count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because you want to display the ids for records that don't exist.  You can do that with a subquery and a `cross join`.  Then use an `outer join` back to the original table and `conditional aggregation` to get your results:

```
select t.a, t.b, 
  count(case when t.b = 'a+b' and y.b in ('a','b') then 1 
        when t.b = 'c+d' and y.b in ('c','d') then 1 
        end) 
from ( 
  select distinct t.a, 
      t2.b
  from yourtable t 
      cross join (select 'a+b' b union all select 'c+d') t2
) t left join yourtable y on t.a = y.a
group by t.a, t.b
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b0da/5)